# Use of link-Checker (ruby)

Tags: ruby, link-checking

Has anyone used the [link-checker gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/link-checker)?

I don't want to use it in a project I want to write a small script to test links on a web app.

I cant seem to figure out how to use it.  Trying to `require` it doesn't work but saying `gem 'link-checker'` does result in true.

I'm getting nowhere trying to play with it in IRB.  Can someone let me know what I am missing?

Comment: " Can someone let me know what I am missing?" You are missing source code or example output showing what you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read [the documentation](http://www.ryanalynporter.com/2012/10/06/introducing-the-link-checker-ruby-gem/)? Link-checker *is* a small script designed to check links already.

That page shows examples of it running from the command-line, not from inside IRB or Ruby code. In other words, it is a command-line app, not code you `require`:

> Usage:
>
> Just give it the target that you want it to scan. For example, if you have an Octopress site then your output HTML is in the public directory, so call it with:

```
check-links 'public'
```

> Or if you want to check the links on a live site, then give it a URL instead:

```
check-links 'http://www.ryanalynporter.com'
```

> If you don’t pass any target, then the default is to scan the “./” directory. If you have a Jekyll site that you deploy to GitHub Pages, then you can check the links with just:

```
check-links
```

Comment: I did try and read the documentation.  My problem is that I didn't understand it. Thanks for the help